# JTable Adding cell values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

//Tell if this needs more info

I want to add the integers inside a cell in a column.
Here's my code:

```
// it's in a mouse listener, eveything works fine, but what I want to do is to add
// the values (for ex. 300,400,500) 

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    if(e.getClickCount() == 2) {
        JTable tbl = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int selectedRow = tbl.getSelectedRow();
        int tbl1_col = 0; // table 1's column to get the data from
        int tbl2_col = 0; // table 2's column to put the data to

   ((DefaultTableModel)tbl2.getModel()).addRow(new Object[] {null,null,null,null}); 
   //to automatically add a new row

    while(tbl1_col<tbl1.getColumnCount()) {
            tbl2.setValueAt(tbl1.getValueAt(selectedRow,tbl1_col),tbl2_row,tbl2_col);
            // Setting the value to be put on to table 2 from table 1

            System.out.println(tbl2.getValueAt(tbl2_row,3));

            tbl1_col++;
            tbl2_col++;

                if(rcol==tbl1.getColumnCount()){
                            tbl2_row++;
                }

                label.setText(String.valueOf(totalAmount));
     }
}
```

There's a System.out.println over there to see what values are inside
and the outputs were:

```
null null null 300
```

My code to add the values:

```
totalAmount = totalAmount + (int) tbl2.getValueAt(tbl2_row,3));
```

The error I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556) & [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/418556)

Comment: *"//Tell if this needs more info"*  Um...  Do you have a question, and if so, what is it?

Comment: `totalAmount = totalAmount + (int) tbl2.getValueAt(tbl2_row,3));`  I guess this line is throwing the error since you have null values in the table. try
`totalAmount = totalAmount + (int) (tbl2.getValueAt(tbl2_row,3) == null ? 0 : tbl2.getValueAt(tbl2_row,3));`

Comment: can you post the complete code?

Comment: @eatSleepCode I dunno if this is legit right. I replaced the "((DefaultTableModel)tbl2.getModel()).addRow(new Object[] {null,null,null,null})" replacing null with 0's and it works